# Is there something like esbuild for serverless python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, serverless-framework

I come from working with nodejs and serverless framework, where I can configure esbuild so that functions that require other functions are in a single bundle file.
Now I am working python with serverless framework, however, when I import an external function, and deploy. In the function bundle the whole project is uploaded. Clearly this would increase costs and delay the startup of the functions.

I have been reading about mock plugins `serverless-python-individually`, `serverless-package-python-functions` but i have not been able to package the function and its dependencies individually.

Is there any way to package the dependencies of the lambda functions individually?

example:

In nodejs I have the following structure:

```
api/
├─ v1/
│  ├─ handler/
│  │  ├─ fileHandler.js
│  ├─ anotherlambda/
│  │  ├─ index.js
│  ├─ s3Storage/
│  │  ├─ index.js
serverless.yml
```

When I deploy, it looks like this:

```
api/
├─ v1/
│  ├─ handler/
│  │  ├─ fileHandler.js
```

Where in fileHandler.js the code of the s3Storage/index.js dependency is inserted.

In python I have the following structure:

```
api/
├─ v1/
│  ├─ handler/
│  │  ├─ fileHandler.py
│  ├─ anotherlambda/
│  │  ├─ hello.py
│  ├─ s3Storage/
│  │  ├─ index.py
```

I would like to know if there is a way to package it in the same way as with nodejs esbuild.

Comment: have you looked into the [cdk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/work-with-cdk-python.html) tool?

Comment: Could you share an example of your configuration file with both python and node functions? Are you using `package: individually`?